# 2002 Ford Escape oil in coolant

Tags: ford, oil, escape

Oil in coolant in reservoir and have oil leak from oil pan in 2002 Ford Escape. Oil pan is not leaking as badly since oil is in coolant. Is car worth keeping? How expensive? Has 166,000 miles. Just put on new battery and expensive new tire, and recent new windshield.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your head gasket is gone. Be prepared to spend $1000 - $1500 for the repairs of the head gasket alone. The other oil leak needs to be fixed as well, costing extra.

You didn't mention what other problems this car has, and how many miles there are on the odometer. Typically, a car that is this old will have quite large problem list.

If the car has been well taken care of, and the odometer amount isn't huge, I would go ahead and allocate $2000 for the repair budget.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to confirm is have your car diagnosed using a compression test and a leak test.

If oil on coolant reservoir, but not in oil dip stick and no milk like substance on oil cap. Then it might just be the oil cooler for this model.

If however, oil exist like a milky substance on the oil dip stick, oil cap, then yes, that we can confirm somewhere on the cylinder head gasket will be the culprit.

I have the same car, 2003, 2.0 escape. Also with a busted oil cooler and to be replaced soon.

[image]